# ADO.NET Transactions

Tags: ado.net

With ADO.net, if I fill a data adapter without implicitly doing a BeginTransaction, does a "Transaction" happen anyway? If not, then what would be the default isolation level?

Answer (score 1):

No transaction is implicit with the DataAdapter.

Answer (score 1):

To run transaction on your data adapter simply use TransactionScope.

```
using (var ts = new TransactionScope())
{
   // do your data adapter related code
   // ...


   ts.Complete();
}
```

When using TransactionScope then you can specify IsolationLevel (e.g. Serializable) as well. The default isolation level on TransactionScope is Serializable.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to to explicitly create a transaction. Along with TransactionScope you can use [SqlTransaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction(v=vs.110).aspx).

For example:

```
            var connString = "Data Source=(local);Integrated security=SSPI; Initial Catalog=Northwind";
            var sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders";

            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                var da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
                var ds = new DataSet();

                // load  data from the data source into the DataSet
                da.Fill(ds, "Orders");

                // start the transaction
                SqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction();

                // associate transaction with the data adapter command objects
                da.DeleteCommand.Transaction = tran;
                da.InsertCommand.Transaction = tran;
                da.UpdateCommand.Transaction = tran;

                // modify the data in the DataSet
                // submit changes, commit or rollback, and close the connection

                try
                {
                    da.Update(ds, "Orders");
                    // commit if successful
                    tran.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    tran.Rollback();
                }
            }
```